Urine filled apartments?!?! Tenant question! Can I get out of this lease? (Indiana)
I recently signed a hefty 15 month lease at a unit that was shown to me in very cold conditions (heat was turned off during 10 degree weather, fresh paint slapped on, could not smell a thing other than wet paint). However, once things dried out, an intense cat urine smell started to permeate the whole unit.
I brought it up with management, who contacted a "cleaning company" that proceeded to SOAK my carpets and ashed their cigarettes in my unit. So I now have a very pissy dwelling with a wafting of cigarettes.
Is this a violation of any lease than can be reasonably drafted in Indiana? In the agreement, it is clear there will be heavy penalties for any early break.
I paid for an independent, certified home inspector to come in and document the unit. I have not disclosed this to management. He verified the state of the carpet (pulled it up then tacked it back) and ran mold tests/radon.
Am I screwed no matter what? I feel like I'm doing the right thing... but my family keeps insisting nothing will come of it and I'm wasting time/money. I'm just so upset that the apartment I'm paying for ($1320 a month) is just so...unlivable. I get migraines just being in the place and I don't trust this management team at all to place me in a safe unit.
This is not mentioning the rampant drug use/ambulance calls/cop calls/
Thank you all, blunt advice is appreciated the most!!!!
Tell me where I went wrong!

Talk to a lawyer licensed to operate in your jurisdiction. This site doesn't offer people legal advice.

While the site doesn't offer legal advice, it isn't beyond its mandate to point out that in most US states if not all there is an implicit (or explicit) "warranty of habitability" which may be breached by the strong odor.  A landlord/tenant lawyer in your jurisdiction will know whether the conditions in your apartment rise to that level (in other words, whether the odor is in fact strong enough to implicate the warranty of habitability) and whether the landlord could limit the remedy to additional cleaning or whether it would allow you to get out of the lease.
